Rescale axes concerning visible artists only
I have a request regarding the use of autoscale_view(). I was expecting it to scale the plot considering only the visible artists, but it does not have such an effect.
I have a small test script as follows, any help is welcome:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x1 = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)
y1 = np.sin(x1)
x2 = np.linspace(5, 15, 100)
y2 = np.cos(x2)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_title('Click on legend line to toggle line on/off')
(line1, ) = ax.plot(x1, y1, lw=2, label='1 Hz')
(line2, ) = ax.plot(x2, y2, lw=2, label='2 Hz')
leg = ax.legend()

lines = [line1, line2]
map_legend_to_ax = {}  # Will map legend lines to original lines.

pickradius = 5
for legend_line, ax_line in zip(leg.get_lines(), lines):
    legend_line.set_picker(pickradius)
    map_legend_to_ax[legend_line] = ax_line

def on_pick(event):
    legend_line = event.artist
    ax_line = map_legend_to_ax[legend_line]
    visible = not ax_line.get_visible()
    ax_line.set_visible(visible)
    legend_line.set_alpha(1.0 if visible else 0.2)

    ax.relim()
    ax.autoscale_view()
    fig.canvas.draw()

fig.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', on_pick)
plt.show()


The relim() method doesn't ignore invisible curves, therefore axes limits should be set explicitly.
## the first part of your code
def on_pick(event):
    legend_line = event.artist
    ax_line = map_legend_to_ax[legend_line]
    visible = not ax_line.get_visible()
    ax_line.set_visible(visible)
    legend_line.set_alpha(1.0 if visible else 0.2)

    # update the axes limits considering only visible curves
    ax_lines = [line for line in lines if line.get_visible()]
    if ax_lines:
        ax.set_xlim(
            min(line.get_xdata().min() for line in ax_lines),
            max(line.get_xdata().max() for line in ax_lines)
        )
        ax.set_ylim(
            min(line.get_ydata().min() for line in ax_lines),
            max(line.get_ydata().max() for line in ax_lines)
        )
    else:
        ax.set_xlim(0, 1)  # Reset to default if no curves are visible
        ax.set_ylim(0, 1)

    fig.canvas.draw()

fig.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', on_pick)
plt.show()


Yes I find your proposition good.
I have added some margins.

Here is my answer including a margin of 5%
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x1 = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)
y1 = np.sin(x1)
x2 = np.linspace(5, 15, 100)
y2 = np.cos(x2)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_title('Click on legend line to toggle line on/off')
(line1,) = ax.plot(x1, y1, lw=2, label='1 Hz')
(line2,) = ax.plot(x2, y2, lw=2, label='2 Hz')
leg = ax.legend()

lines = [line1, line2]
map_legend_to_ax = {}  # Will map legend lines to original lines.

pickradius = 5
for legend_line, ax_line in zip(leg.get_lines(), lines):
    legend_line.set_picker(pickradius)
    map_legend_to_ax[legend_line] = ax_line

def on_pick(event):
    legend_line = event.artist
    ax_line = map_legend_to_ax[legend_line]
    visible = not ax_line.get_visible()
    ax_line.set_visible(visible)
    legend_line.set_alpha(1.0 if visible else 0.2)

    visible_lines = [line for line in lines if line.get_visible()]
    if visible_lines:
        x_min = min(line.get_xdata().min() for line in visible_lines)
        x_max = max(line.get_xdata().max() for line in visible_lines)

        y_min = min(line.get_ydata().min() for line in visible_lines)
        y_max = max(line.get_ydata().max() for line in visible_lines)

        x_margin = (x_max - x_min) * 0.05
        y_margin = (y_max - y_min) * 0.05
        
        ax.set_xlim(x_min - x_margin, x_max + x_margin)
        ax.set_ylim(y_min - y_margin, y_max + y_margin)

        fig.canvas.draw()

fig.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', on_pick)
plt.show()


Thanks
